# Can I use an assignment in a switch case?

Tags: c, while-loop, switch-statement, case, assignment-operator

Baby programming student here. An assignment asks for me to use a few loops to count from 1 - 100, and in one of the loops I have to include a switch statement that prints some things depending on the conditions.
Here is what the assignment is:
"Create a basic program that accomplishes the following requirements:

1. Uses a for statement to count from 1 to 100.
2. Uses a while statement to count from 1 to 100.
3. Use a do while statement to count from 1 to 100.
4. Using a switch statement in one of the loops , print to the screen if a number is:
   Less than or equal to 10,
   Greater than or equal to 11 but less than 20,
   Greater than 21."

I can complete the looping statements just fine, and I can write a switch statement, but putting a switch statement inside of a loop that is already counting seems impossible. From my understanding, a case in a switch statement must be an integral value (like '1') and cannot be an assignment (like 'counter <= 10'). I have done so much research and found no help or clarity from my professor or any youtube tutorial. I am at wits end here; is there something I'm just not understanding about switch statements? I feel so lost.

Comment: Sorry, cant read.

Comment: You can either put multiple (empty) cases after each other `case 1: case 2: /* ... */ case 10: puts("..."); break;` or in your case you could try `switch(i/10) {...}`

Comment: Something like `switch((i <= 10) ? 1 : (i < 20) ? 2 : (i <= 21) ? 3 : 4)` would work, though that's code no one would write in real life, so I question the wisdom of that assignment.

Comment: It seems like a poorly designed assignment. It is not impossible or even difficult; it just calls for a solution that is either tedious (write all the `case` labels) or a kludge (use evaluations of inequalities as `switch` criteria). Just slog through it.

Comment: Thank you all for your help! I had a feeling I wasn't the only one put off by the assignment. You all helped very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have several `case` labels before the same statement:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 1: case 2: case 3: case 4: case 5:
        case 6: case 7: case 8: case 9: case 10:
            printf("%d is less than or equal to 10\n", i);
            break;
        case 11: case 12: case 13: case 14: case 15:
        case 16: case 17: case 18: case 19:
            printf("%d is greater than or equal to 11 but less than 20\n", i);
            break;
        case 20:
        case 21:
            /* nothing printed for 20 or 21? */
            break;
        default:
            /* cases 22 to 100 */
            printf("%d is greater than 21\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: @0___________ It's a code fragment to be bunged in a function. OK, I fixed two typos. It's bedtime! :-)

Comment: Now is OK :) ___

Answer (score 2):

Use the `switch() case` in this case is not a very good idea and shows that your teacher did not have a better idea for the exercise :)

Another maths

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        switch (i/10 + !!(i%10) + i/20 + (i > 21))
        {
            case 1:
            printf("%d is less than or equal to 10\n", i);
            break;
        case 2:
            printf("%d is greater than or equal to 11 but less than 20\n", i);
            break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
            /* nothing printed for 20 or 21? */
            break;
        default:
            /* cases 22 to 100 */
            printf("%d is greater than 21\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

As an addition to another answers you can also use gcc extension:

```
    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++)
    {
        switch (i)
        {
        case 1 ... 10:
            printf("%d is less than or equal to 10\n", i);
            break;
        case 11 ... 19:
            printf("%d is greater than or equal to 11 but less than 20\n", i);
            break;
        case 20:
        case 21:
            /* nothing printed for 20 or 21? */
            break;
        default:
            /* cases 22 to 100 */
            printf("%d is greater than 21\n", i);
            break;
        }
    }
```

Code was partially stolen from @IanAbbot answer (due to laziness)

But it is not standard C.

Answer (score 0):

As an idea. You can use the conditional operator.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    while ( 1 )
    {
        printf( "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ");
        
        unsigned int n;
        
        if ( scanf( "%u", &n ) != 1 || n == 0 ) break;
        
        switch ( n <= 10 ? 0 : ( n < 20 ? 1 : ( 21 < n ) ? 2 : 3 ) )
        {
            case 0:
                puts( "The number is less than or equal tp 10" );
                break;
                
            case 1:
                puts( "The number is less than 20" );
                break;
                
            case 2:
                puts( "the number is greater than 21" );
                break;
                
            case 3: default:
                break;
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 10
The number is less than or equal tp 10
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 11
The number is less than 20
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 22
the number is greater than 21
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 21
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```